# Jquery - can't get selector of nested div to animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried several SEVERAL variations on this but can't get the proper selector of a nested div. I need to animate this div, and since no animations are occurring Im left to conclude Im not grabbing the right selector.

Here is my animation:

```
$(".lab1").hover(function(){
    $(".panel-group .panel", this).stop(true, false).animate({ marginTop: "-80px;"});  //Trying to get this
    $(".panel", this).stop(true, false).animate({ height: "140px"});

}, function() {
     $("div.panel.panel-default", this).stop(true, false).animate({ marginTop: "0px;"});
    $(".panel", this).stop(true, false).animate({ height: "98px" });
});
```

The 2nd line with the marginTop is the one not happening. Ive gone in chrome and tried to use the selector there but nothing works. Here is my html:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" style = "text-align: left;margin-top: 30px;">
<div class="lab1">  <!--CTedit -->
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i><span style="margin-left: 12px; display: inline-block;"></span>Lab Focus: Cloud Management with vRealize Operations & <nobr>vRealize Automation</nobr></a>
      </h4>
    </div>
```

I am trying to get the 2nd panel-default. How can I get the selector?

Comment: Try using `$(this).find(".panel").stop....`

Comment: Didn't work - I have multiple things in there with .panel so that might be the problem. Tried finding .panel-default but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

`.panel-group` is not a child element of `.lab1`

Comment: No I know I was trying something else - Ive tried .panel-default .panel.panel-default, div.panel.panel-default

Comment: _"I am trying to get the 2nd panel-default"_ Only one `.panel-default` element appears at `html` at Question? Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Answer (score 0):

The animation is happening but your code below the animation is stoping it. Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xo655gx4/3/) .
Also you have some wrongs there. `marginTop: "-80px;"` it doesn't need `;` at the end `marginTop: "-80px"`
This line of code stop the animation that's why you can't get it.

```
$(".panel", this).stop(true, false).animate({ height: "140px"});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call twice the `stop()` function on an element, the second call end the first animation before it starts. Plus don't put a `;` in your string, and animate `this` separately. This code is working :

```
$(".lab1").hover(function() {
    $(".panel-group .panel").stop(true, false).animate({ marginTop: "-80px"});  //Trying to get this
    $(".panel").animate({ height: "140px"});
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({marginTop: "-80px",  height: "140px"});

}, function() {
    $(".panel-group .panel").stop(true, false).animate({ marginTop: "0px"});
    $(".panel").animate({ height: "98px" });
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({marginTop: "0px",  height: "98px"});
});
```